# How to replace a word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have a string: "Someone one one-way"
And I want to replace THE WORD "one" with THE WORD "two".

Note: I don't want "someone" or "one-way" to change.

I tried to use str.replace(/one/g , "two");
But the result was "Sometwo two two-way"

This is not the intended result...
I want to get "Someone two one-way"

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED. THANKS IN ADVANCE....

Comment: I am clueless... :(

Comment: `str.replace(/ one /g, " two ")`

Comment: @Schleis that doesnt work with punctuation

Comment: @Mark Baijens Yes that's where I am struggling

Comment: @kevin b its not a duplicate... Because In this post I asked for replacing a word NOT MERE ALL OCCURRENCES ...

Comment: @William your accepted answer replaces *all* occurrences that match the regexp. There just so happens to only be one in your given string. You never stated you only wanted to replace one occurrence, you simply pointed out that you wanted it to catch a specific type of occurance, one that isn't part of another word. The dupe target has several answers that accomplish that.

Comment: Ok I must say its a special case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the spaces too:

```
//var str = "Someone one one-way";
var str = "one one Someone one one-way one,one";

var replace='two';
//using lookahead and lookbehind
var result= str.replace(/(?<=[^a-zA-Z-]|^)one(?=[^a-zA-Z-]|$)/gm , "two");

console.log(result);
//result: two two Someone two one-way two,two
```

Comment: using also lookahead and lookbehind

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('STR.SPLIT(" ONE ").JOIN(" TWO ")'.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Ok but what if the word was at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Like "someone one."

Comment: Well, that wouldn't work anymore obviously

Comment: With punctuations I created a large code... It was messy! I took into account all the common punctuation marks like .,!?;: etc.

Answer (score -1):

try this regex:

```html
\s(one)\s
```

you may add modify it for case sensitive.

Comment: May i kno the reason for downvote?

Answer (score -1):

```js
let input = "Someone one one-way"
output = input.split(" ").map((item)=> item ==='one'? 'two' : item).join(" ");
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
.replace(/\bone\b(?!-)/g , "two")
```

`\b` matches on a word boundary.

(?!-) is a negative lookahead because you do not want to replace one if followed by a dash. \b recognizes the dash as a word boundary.

There is another pitfall when you have something like "-one".

Use this if this is a Problem:

```
.replace(/[^-]\bone\b(?!-)/g , function(x){return x.substring(0,1) + 'two'})
```

Ideally you would use negative look ahead, but this is currently not supported by all Browsers.